# How to make a pop up image like an advertisement? [Android]

Tags: java, android, image, popup

I've encountered a lot of pop up images like the example below, i've made a pop up image but there is no close button at the top left corner, do u guys have any idea how to make a pop up image with close button at the top left cornel like the example below in Android?

[image: Image pop up example]

Comment: you have to make a custom layout and inflate it as popup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your own Dialog with your custom layout

```
Dialog dialog;

private void showDialog() {
    // custom dialog
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    ImageButton close = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    Button buy = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);

    // Close Button
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //TODO Close button action
        }
    });

    // Buy Button
    buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //TODO Buy button action
        }
    });

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    dialog.show();
}
```

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/images" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="BUY"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnBuy"
                android:text="Thank You (Domestic Album Version)"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:text="Still Not Gettin' Any, 2004" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Result is:

[image: Screenshot of layout with Custom Dialog]

Comment: when you define set the custom dialog components, is it gonna automatically detected wtih the current activity that using another layout, because the custom dialog layout is different??

Answer (score -2):

You can use this library. There is close button on top right corner. only need to set image only.

https://github.com/chathuralakmal/AndroidImagePopup