# Add button at the bottom of the dialog

Tags: android, dialog

Currently i have a `dialog` that shows an image that is being clicked by the user.

What i want to do, is to add a `button` on the `bottom` of the `dialog`.

**This is my current code:**

```
  public void showImage(Drawable drawable) {
        final Dialog builder = new Dialog(mContext);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));

//        builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
//                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //nothing;
            }
        });

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        Button mClose = new Button(mContext);
        mClose.setText("CLOSE");
        mClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                builder.dismiss();
            }
        });
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        builder.addContentView(mClose,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        builder.show();
    }
```

**The current code have :**
The `button` is in the upper  left of the `imageview` where it should be on the below of `imageview`.

Comment: why don't you create custom dialog ??

Comment: im trying to lessen the work as much possible, if this is possible then it would be better.

Comment: it is better to create custom dialog

Comment: @stackersoverfllawrerstacking you can't get good design in your case

Answer (score 1):

Try This

afer

```
builder.addContentView(mClose,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Add This

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

//yourButton

```
    builder.addContentView(yourButton,lp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to create your own custom dialog and show image and button.

Please look into below similar links, this might help you.

[How to make a pop up image like an advertisement? [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749735/how-to-make-a-pop-up-image-like-an-advertisement-android)

[Show AlertDialog with ImageView without any padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954561/show-alertdialog-with-imageview-without-any-padding)

Thanks